# Total Price between date range (like hotel reservation seasons)

Tags: mysql, sql, date, range

```
 id       carID     date1         date2      price
 ---      ----     ---------    ---------    -----
 1        1       1000-01-01    9999-12-31   100

 2        2       1000-01-01    2014-06-06   100 
 3        2       2014-06-07    2014-06-07   150
 4        2       2014-06-08    9999-12-31   100

 5        3       1000-01-01    2014-06-01   150
 6        3       2014-06-02    2014-07-01   200
 7        3       2014-07-02    2014-07-25   300
 8        3       2014-07-26    9999-12-31   100
```

This is my price table; I want to calculate total price with my dates range.

I want to display all cars with total price;

for example my filter dates:

**date1:** 2014-06-01
**date2:** 2014-06-22

### RESULTS

```
CARID    TOTAL
------ ------
1      2100
2      2150
3      4150
```

And I try this , but it is only for one carID.
[calculate price between given dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807024/calculate-price-between-given-dates)
Also This;
[calculate price between given dates in multiple ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306404/calculate-price-between-given-dates-in-multiple-ranges)
Example : https://olaykredi.com

Comment: could you add expected results, please

Comment: "Calculate hotel booking"?  "Display all cars"?  At least one of us is very confused.

Comment: @horaciux three cars will be list. cars ID and total Price.
carID 1 -> 100*21 = 2100
carID 2 -> (100*5)+150+(15*100)=2150
carID 3 -> 150+(20*200)=4150

Comment: @GordonLinoff like hotel reservation system, carID or hotelID. date range is important for me

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have variables `@date1` and `@date2`, you can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select carid,
       sum(1 + greatest(least(date2, @date2) - greatest(date1, @date1), 0) * price)
from table t
group by carid;
```

This just replaces the boundaries of each period in the table with the intersection with the outer boundaries.  It then sums up the duration times the price.  The `1 +` seems to handle the case that `date2` appears to be a valid date for the price, rather then the first date when it is not active.

Comment: Good Job! it is work. But if date1 and date2 are same not work. I use like this    SUM(greatest(least(f.date2, '$date2') - greatest(f.date1, '$date1'), 0) * f.iTutar)/$day as iTutar

Comment: If months are not same, code does not work, you can check it again please ?

Comment: @imugur . . . What the range means depends on whether the second date is part of the range or not.  Such issues are fixed by judiciously adding or subtracting `1` in calculations.